# How to convert seconds into HH:mm format php

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am having a time duration in seconds. I want show it in HH:mm format. Is there way to do it using php date-time function??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `gmdate()` and set the seconds as param.

Example:

```
$seconds = 20;
$result = gmdate('H:i', $seconds);
```

**Edit**: Ooops... I placed date instead of gmdate... Now I noticed the problem with the timezones with date.
(It's corrected now.)

Comment: This gives `19:00` as output.

Answer (score 5):

If you have seconds you could do:

```
<?php

$sec = 3864;

$h = floor($sec /3600);
$m = floor(($sec - $h *3600) / 60);
$s = $sec % 60;


printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s);

?>
```

output here: http://codepad.org/7ee9Cx03

Answer (score 3):

i found this solution:

function sec_to_his ($seconds)
{
  return gmdate ('H:i:s', $seconds);
}

some other variations can be found on this website: http://codeaid.net/php/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds-(php)

greets stefan.

Comment: Note that the OP just wanted hours and minutes, but this is the simplest solution which seems to work. +1

Answer (score -2):

You could write a function:

```
<?php

function convertToHoursMinutes($seconds) {

    $seconds = intval($seconds);
    $hours = ceil($seconds/3600);
    $minutes = $seconds%3600;

    return sprintf('%d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}

echo '24502 seconds is ' . convertToHoursMinutes(24502);
```

Or you could try searching Google your question.